# How to count number of positive values, given as method argument, in one line?

Tags: java

I have 3 doubles - a, b and c, passed to a method `numPos` as 3 different arguments. I want to count the number of positive valuse among them, hence the method's return type is `int`.
I thought about declaring an `Array/List` and adding the values to it, checking if the value is greater than 0, but I couldn't even do the first part of my idea - declaring a `List` and passing all the values to it. Here's the code I wrote:

```
public static int numPos(double a, double b, double c) {
        return List<double> myList = new List<double>(DoubleStream.of(a,b,c).forEach(i -> myList.add(i))).stream().count();
}
```

Comment: Side note: it's `List<Double>`. You cannot create a collection for a primitive datatype.

Comment: Side note 2: you cannot instantiate an interface. `List` is an interface. It has to be `new ArrayList<>()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily use:

```
return Stream.of(a, b, c).filter(x -> x > 0).count();
```

Note that `count()` return long and not int, you need to change the returned type to long.

---

**Important**: You really complicate your code, and you have many mistakes that you should to avoid in future.